# Create new file if file not found at location

Tags: python

My code is writing exceptions occurred during run into a file. However, my code breaks if file is not present at location. Code needs `ExceptionLog_1.txt` named file to be present at the location.

How do I make changes to code to ensure code creates a new file at location if code breaks for - `file not found error`

My code:

```
def WriteExceptionToFile(self, filingId, traceback):
    count = 1
    fileDir = 'C:/Users/Desktop/SampleTestFiles/ProjectFiles/ExceptionLogFiles/'
    filepath = os.path.join(fileDir, "ExceptionLog_"+str(count)+".txt")

    if os.path.getsize(filepath) < 1048576:
        filepath = os.path.join(fileDir, "ExceptionLog_" + str(count) + ".txt")
    else:
        filepath = os.path.join(fileDir,"ExceptionLog_" + str(count + 1) + ".txt")

    f = open(filepath, 'a+')
    traceback.print_exc(file=f)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Use a context manager to handle files. Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Also I’m pretty sure your code creates the file already, so I’m not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The `'a+'` flag already handles the file creation for you.  However if the *folder path* doesn't exist you'll need to first create the directory.

```
fileDir = 'C:/Users/Desktop/SampleTestFiles/ProjectFiles/ExceptionLogFiles/'

# check if the path exists, create directory if not.
if not(os.path.exists):
    os.mkdir(fileDir)

filepath = os.path.join(fileDir, "ExceptionLog_"+str(count)+".txt")
```

You should also exercise using [context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) to handle your files:

```
with open(filepath, 'a+') as f:
    traceback.print_exc(file=f)
```

If your `fileDir` may have multiple non-existing folder paths, you might consider a recursive `mkdir` function to create all the inner folders:

```
def r_mkdir(pth):
    parent, child = os.path.split(pth)
    if not os.path.exists(parent):
        r_mkdir(parent)
    if not os.path.exists(pth): 
        os.mkdir(pth)

if not(os.path.exists):
    r_mkdir(fileDir)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create file this way with `IOError` exception handling,

```
fileDir = 'C:/Users/Desktop/SampleTestFiles/ProjectFiles/ExceptionLogFiles/'
filepath = os.path.join(fileDir, "ExceptionLog_"+str(count)+".txt")
try:
    fp = open(filepath)
except IOError:
    # If not exists, create the file
    fp = open(filepath, 'w+')
```